# LEA instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86

what does

```
lea    (%edx,%eax,1),%eax
```

do?

Answer (score 25):

It's the equivalent of "eax = edx + eax * 1".

This particular case of `lea` is an inefficient way to write `add %edx, %eax`; only useful if you need to avoid modifying flags.  But unlike `add`, the output can be a register that isn't one of the inputs, and you can do more complex operations.

Generally, `lea (address expression), register` means "compute the address expression and change the register value to that"; other instructions use address expressions for memory access, i.e. `mov (address expression), register` means "compute the address expression and load the value from the resulting address into the register".

Answer (score -1):

Load Effective Address- it's the equivalent of the C unary `&` operator.

Comment: While the `&` operator sometimes compiles to `LEA` they're not equivalent.