# assembly notation clarification lea

Tags: assembly

In the following code, I am having trouble understanding what is happening in the parentheses. Is it doing like %edx + 1 * %ecx or something?

```
lea    (%ecx,%edx,1),%ebx
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the purpose of the LEA instruction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction)

Comment: Ehh, really I was more interested in the conventions of parentheses

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154330/x86-lea-instruction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534617/lea-instruction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the (slightly odd) AT&T syntax for a memory reference at address `ecx + edx * 1`.